# how do you display a different webapp on localhost in Flask Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask-restful

So I have a URL of a web application which I need to host on my local-server. So that if the user opens my server, he directly opens the url of that web application. And after he is done with his work and saves it. I want to take that data that he saves and use it accordingly. I have been trying to do this since 3 days but I am not moving forward in linking my URL to my local host server.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return request.url.replace(request.host_url, 'https://stackoverflow.com')
```

The URL mentioned above is just an example. Can anyone Please help me with this?
I am new to flask and API and Python.

Answer (score 0):

trying see here:  [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#SERVER_NAME) or here(on Russia language but google translate can help: [question-it](https://question-it.com/questions/2753642/ispolzovanie-flask-dlja-vozvrata-obrabotannogo-url-adresa-na-storone-servera)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.